# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined, run in browser

Tags: javascript

So I have copied this code, restructured it a bit but am getting the error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined'. Could you please help in getting this working ? Many thanks

Searched various articles. Says require cannot be called within a browser but some articles say you can

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
chart = {
  const links = data.links.map(d => Object.create(d));
  const nodes = data.nodes.map(d => Object.create(d));

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force("link", d3.forceLink(links).id(d => d.id))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  const svg = d3.select(DOM.svg(width, height));

  const link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#999")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.6)
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .join("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", d => Math.sqrt(d.value));

  const node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", color)
      .call(drag(simulation));

  node.append("title")
      .text(d => d.id);

  simulation.on("tick", () => {
    link
        .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
        .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
        .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
        .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
        .attr("cx", d => d.x)
        .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  });

  invalidation.then(() => simulation.stop());

  return svg.node();
}


data = d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/4062045/raw/5916d145c8c048a6e3086915a6be464467391c62/miserables.json")

height = 600


color = {
  const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
  return d => scale(d.group);
}


</style>
<svg class="chart"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<script>



drag = simulation => {

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }

  return d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended);
}

d3 = require("d3@5")


</script>
```

Need to get this working running locally

https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph

Comment: D3 should be accessible via your `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>` directly. No need for require (which is only supposed to be used via node)

Comment: You have JavaScript code in a `<style>` tag.

Comment: Im a noob. Could you help in restructring this for me ?